# select last non-contemporaneous date in group

Tags: r, dplyr

People are buying stuff and I have the dates when someone last purchased the item in their zip code. I want to grab the last *noncontemporaneous* date in that group.

```
ZCTA5 = c("b", "c", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "c")
App.Complete.Date = c("2005-01-23", "2005-01-23",
                      "2006-07-13", "2006-11-21",
                      "2006-11-21", "2006-11-21",
                      "2007-01-01", "2007-01-01",
                      "2007-01-01", "2007-01-01")
xxx <- data.frame(ZCTA5,App.Complete.Date) %>% 
     arrange(ZCTA5,App.Complete.Date); xxx
 Last.Unique.Date.In.ZCTA5 =c(NA, "2006-07-13", "2006-07-13", "2006-07-13", NA, "2005-01-23", 
                         "2005-01-23", NA, "2005-01-23", "2006-11-21")
```

**Desired output**

```
   ZCTA5 App.Complete.Date Last.Unique.Date.In.ZCTA5
1      a        2006-07-13                      <NA>
2      a        2007-01-01                2006-07-13
3      a        2007-01-01                2006-07-13
4      a        2007-01-01                2006-07-13
5      b        2005-01-23                      <NA>
6      b        2006-11-21                2005-01-23
7      b        2006-11-21                2005-01-23
8      c        2005-01-23                      <NA>
9      c        2006-11-21                2005-01-23
10     c        2007-01-01                2006-11-21
```

I don't want to drop any observations. Mutating in place would be ideal, but I understand joining by ZCTA5 and (not shown but I do have it) individual ID later would be fine.

I couldn't figure out a way to mutate a new variable by lagging the unique App.Complete.Date values so I am stuck. Additionally, slicing has been too cumbersome since I still need the last date without removing contemporaneous dates.

EDIT: If the NA is the same row's App.Complete.Date, that's acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```r
xxx = xxx %>% 
  mutate(App.Complete.Date = as.Date(App.Complete.Date),
         rn = row_number())
```

Initial setup to ensure date column is of type date. Adding row numbers in order to preserve duplicate dates in origin.

```r
yyy = xxx %>%
  left_join(xxx, by = "ZCTA5") %>%
  # discard all the out-of-scope dates
  mutate(App.Complete.Date.y = ifelse(App.Complete.Date.y < App.Complete.Date.x,
                                      App.Complete.Date.y, NA)) %>%
  # we need to include row number here to preserve all rows in the original
  group_by(ZCTA5, App.Complete.Date.x, rn.x) %>%
  # na.rm = TRUE handles all the missing values removed in the previous mutate
  summarise(App.Complete.Date.y = max(App.Complete.Date.y, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  # summarise may return numeric type rather than date type - convert back
  mutate(App.Complete.Date.y = as.Date(App.Complete.Date.y, origin = "1970-01-01")) %>%
  # rename to output
  select(ZCTA5,
         App.Complete.Date = App.Complete.Date.x,
         Last.Unique.Date.In.ZCTA5 = App.Complete.Date.y)
```

You may need to change the `origin` argument in the last mutate depending on what the base date in your system is set at. When my computer returned 13342 instead of '2006-07-13', I determined the base date was '1970-01-01' because '2006-07-13' is 13342 days after '1970-01-01'.

Comment: Wonderfully done. Thank you.

When applied to my real data this doesn't work well preserving other columns, but I'll find a way to make it work.

Comment: You are welcome. To preserve other columns, one option is to add them everywhere there are `___.x` variables. Another option is to do this process, keep the row number and then join `yyy` onto `xxx` using row number.